# Custom animation for navigation drawer

Tags: android, animation, menu, navigation-drawer

I've successfully implemented the Navigation Drawer as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)
Now, I'd like to override the default animation for opening/closing. I'd like to use a custom animation. Is it feasible? If so, how can I do it? Thank you very much

Comment: Hey have you find any solution for this?

Comment: It was quite a long time ago, but I don't remember having found a solution, sorry.

Comment: can anyone give a link to how to do this? i have tried creating my custom animation in view in ondraw method but am not able to apply it on navigation view.

Answer (score 0):

You can call openDrawer(int gravity) on the DrawerLayout to make it open the drawer with an animation.

Example:

```
// Delay is in milliseconds
static final int DRAWER_DELAY = 200;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Building NavDrawer logic here. Just a method call would be best.
    ...
    new Handler().postDelayed(openDrawerRunnable(), DRAWER_DELAY);
}

private Runnable openDrawerRunnable() {
    return new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use the default animation, nor delay it. I want to use my own animation (defined in a XML file)